# Java app high availability/failover with persistent TCP server sockets

Tags: java, tcp, high-availability, failover, haproxy

I'm trying to figure out the right pieces to implement a highly available & failover setup for a java based server application (netty). The TCP connections would ideally be up for months if not years (they are used in server to server comms) and would only ever need to go down if the remote server disconnected or due to a uncontrolled network problem. The goal is to not have any single points of failure.

The data within the socket connections looks very similar to protobuf data structures. It's not HTTP.

Thus far I've been looking at keepalived and HAProxy, but neither seem to allow redirecting/failovering a persistent TCP session to a different backend server without disconnecting the front end session.

What i'm trying to figure out is what would be running on the FE1 and BE1 systems as in the below;

```
        |        VIP         |
   +----+----+          +----+----+
   |   FE1   | <-VRRP-> |   FE2   |
   +----+----+          +----+----+
        |                    |               
        |                    |
  ------+---+------------+---+----------                                
            |            | 
        +---+---+    +---+---+
        |  BE1A |    |  BE1B |
        +---+---+    +---+---+
            |            |       
            +------------+
            |            | 
            |            |
        +---+---+    +---+---+
        |  BE2A |    |  BE2B |
        +---+---+    +---+---+
```

External servers connect via the VIP to the active front end (FE) system, which then establishes the TCP connection to the active back-end 1 (BE1) system. Or if a TCP proxy does this; connects to both BE1 systems, and sends traffic to one system.

The BE1 servers run a custom java app which handles ensuring the requests and responses end up at the appropriate BE2 system. This can be modified in any way to handle the connection/stream from the FE servers if need be.

What I'm looking for is if one of the BE1 systems goes down (intentionally or not) is the FE server redirects/re-establishes a connection to the other BE1 system without any disconnect to the connection to the external VIP from the remote server. Ie, transparent failover of persistent TCP connection.

As mentioned before I've looked at keepalived / HAProxy, and from what I can tell they would not work - unless I've missed a plugin/mod to them that might do the trick.

What options are there for what can run on the FE layer? or is there something that can run on the BE1 layer which can handle the failover and notice to java of the socket being moved/resumed on the alternate system (ie can LVS or tcpcp be used with java - I've not found much talk about it).

Thanks!

Comment: What is the reason you want to have the connection not broken? I think you are making it too complicated.  It is better if the clients just reconnect if the connection fails and then get directed to a new server.  There are so many network problems besides "connection broken" that you have to think about anyway.  What if a BE2 server is up, but returning errors.  Or if it is timing out?  It seems like what you need is for FE1 to be a full tcp proxy.  If it forwards a message and it fails it can try and forward to another server.

Comment: @Dave So if we need to do maintenance or updates on the back end systems it can be transparent. Some clients do not notice any disconnects and do reconnect right away, however, others do not reconnect and for any disconnect want incident reports (no matter if it was a 100ms disconnect).

The protocol handles timeouts, app keepalives, and issues, so if a message fails it is handled between the outside server and FE2.

Comment: What I've come down to is that most of the larger clients (and those which complain more) have several connections (they view them in a bundle - so providing one connection is up they are OK), which I can balance between BE1s. This way we could take down one FE1 system and connections would shift to the other, when it's back up we'll just have to drop the failed over connections on the FE1 system to fail them back. So overall it would work. May just be more involved than needed.

Comment: So you need FE1 and FE2 to be proxies then.  The client connection terminates at FE1 and FE2.  The software on FE1 and 2 is smart enough that if a BE* disconnects it will reconnect to a different one. In this case the FE servers cannot be some generic proxy, but something that understands your protocol

Answer (score 0):

i am trying to achive these, I have seen these approach working with Websphere MQ, where you add app to Failover controller.
The advantagens are:

- You just know one IP address
- you dont have to code the switching on the client

Best regards.
Leonel dos Anjos